# EJB injection and EntityManager are both null

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I am using eclipse with GlassFish 5. I am making a three tier application using swing. First I made a JPA Project and then added EJB Facet.
Schema is being successfully created with entity classes.

I am getting a null on my EJB injection and EntityManager Injection.

In my controller I have injected EJB as follows:

```
public class BookQueries {

    @EJB
    private  BookService bs;

    public BookQueries() {
    /*try {

        Context context = new InitialContext();         
        Object fObj = context
            .lookup("java:global/LMS/BookService!com.lms.service.BookService");
        bs=(BookService)fObj;
    }catch(NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Naming Exception while lookup of bean object");
    }
    */
}
```

As you can see in controller constructor I have also tried JNDI lookup but I still get null.Here is my EJB class in which I have Injected EntityManager which also is null.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BookService {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "LMS")
    EntityManager em;

}
```

Here is my Persistence.xml file

```
<persistence-unit name="LMS">   
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/lms</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation"
                  value="drop-and-create-tables" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have previously made Web Dynamic Application on Eclipse and it all works fine there.

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the latter, your `BookService` should have:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "LMS") // not 'name'
```

or you can try without any `unitName` if there are no other PUs in use.

Then about your `BookQueries` is it itself a managed bean I cannot see any bean related annotations in it? If it is not then the `@EJB` stuff will not be initialized. For example, if it is meant to be a `Singleton` bean add annotations:

```
@Singleton
@Startup  // makes it to be initialized at app startup
```

or

```
@LocalBean
```

Doing like `new BookQueries()` does not make it managed and thus no injection or such thing happens. You need to annotate it (or configure it somewhere in control panel of Glassfish or in beans.xml) to be known bean. And then inject it to some managed context (UI class?), for example with `@Inject` or `@Resource` quite like you inject `BookService`.

Also I recommend you to check out if you should use annotations like `@Inject` or `@Resource` rather than `@EJB`.

Comment: I did tried unitName instead of name before but it doesn't work. I have used only "name" before for web application and it worked then.
BookQueries is a controller class why does it need EJB class annotations. and my EJB class is stateless session bean i.e , BookService

Comment: So do you have somewhere configuration which tells that it is a controller or is there some annotation missing from the class?

Comment: No. I don't. I'm just making an object of this class in UI class and I'm Passing the values to it. It feels like this is something I have done wrong. Kindly explain how should I do it.